# Postgresql for loop for abc analysis

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

I'm trying to make an ABC analysis. I should classify the sold articles inside the group they belong to. So the SQL with which I'm trying to achieve this is this one. The query starts running, but even if I let it run for hours it doesn't get any result and it doesn't finish. When I try the same query, but without the loop - just with one group, everything is fine. Could someone help me with figuring out what is wrong with the loop. Thanks :)

```
DO $$
DECLARE v integer;
BEGIN

FOR v in select id_group from ft_sales
LOOP

WITH ProductSales AS
(
    -- Get the total for each Product Model
    SELECT 
       id_group,
        id_article,
        SUM(qty) Sales
    FROM ft_sales
    WHERE id_date>2190  
GROUP BY
    id_group,
    id_article

)
-- Calculate culmulative total and categorise it based on the percentage.
-- Product Model that have high sales amount and make up the first 70% 
-- will be classified as A, the next 20% is B and the rest is C.
-- Product Models in A generate more revenue.
INSERT INTO classification ( id_group,id_article, sales, cum_sales, total, cum_perc, class )
SELECT ps.id_group,
    ps.id_article, 
    ps.Sales,
    SUM(ps.Sales) OVER (ORDER BY ps.Sales DESC) AS CumulativeSales,
    SUM(ps.Sales) OVER () AS TotalSales,
    SUM(ps.Sales) OVER (ORDER BY ps.Sales DESC) / SUM(ps.Sales) OVER () AS CumulativePercentage,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(ps.Sales) OVER (ORDER BY ps.Sales DESC) / SUM(ps.Sales) OVER () <= 0.7 
            THEN 'A'
        WHEN SUM(ps.Sales) OVER (ORDER BY ps.Sales DESC) / SUM(ps.Sales) OVER () <= 0.9 
            THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
    END AS Class
FROM    ProductSales ps
GROUP BY ps.id_group,
    ps.id_article,
    ps.Sales;
END LOOP;
    END $$;
```

Comment: Did you resolve this performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you. **Disclaimer:** Untested. The goal is to only select the info you need **once** and then loop over it for insertion.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN
        SELECT  ps.id_group
                , ps.id_article
                , ps.Sales
                , SUM(ps.sales) OVER (ORDER BY ps.sales DESC) AS cumulative_sales
                , SUM(ps.sales) OVER () AS total_sales
                , SUM(ps.sales) OVER (ORDER BY ps.Sales DESC) / SUM(ps.Sales) OVER() AS cum_perc
                , CASE
                     WHEN SUM(ps.sales) OVER (ORDER BY ps.sales DESC) / SUM(ps.sales) OVER() <= 0.7 
                         THEN 'A'
                     WHEN SUM(ps.sales) OVER (ORDER BY ps.sales DESC) / SUM(ps.sales) OVER() <= 0.9 
                         THEN 'B'
                     ELSE 'C'
                  END AS class
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  id_group
                   , id_article
                   , SUM(qty) AS sales
            FROM ft_sales
            WHERE id_date > 2190
            GROUP BY id_group, id_article
        ) ps
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO classification ( id_group,id_article, sales, cum_sales, total, cum_perc, class )
        VALUES (rec.id_group, rec.id_article, rec.sales, rec.cumulative_sales, rec.total_sales, rec.cum_perc, rec.class)
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine, thank you. However it looks like I'm missing something of the logic, because I need to classify (abc) articles inside every group, but now there are groups where everything is class "C".